# Issue with character models in unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, unityscript

I am using the Unity 4 game engine and I have two scripts, one that tells the enemy to attack the player, and one that lets the player attack the enemy. The enemy can attack the player, but the other script does not work. If i apply the script to a game object such as a capsule or cube, the script works fine, but not when i apply it to an imported character model. The script basically works by checking the enemy's health and destroying the gameobject if it is equal to or below zero. I have a feeling it has to do with the character model not being an actual game object but i am pretty sure it is. Can anyone help?

Comment: please post the code for better solution..

Answer (score 0):

When you make the enemy character. Make an empty game object. Then create your enemy inside of that object. In the hierarchy view it should be parented by the empty object. You can also do this by dragging the enemy to the empty game object in the hierarchy view. Then attach the script to the empty game object instead of the model.

Answer (score 0):

### Solution

Please check all the tags you are applying to the scripts .No Script could able to work until unless the tagging is done . The tagging help the game object to differentiate between normal object and the enemy so the tagging plays a vital role to run scripts .

[image: Tagging in Unity]